# Base class in C#... that can be inherited from like an interface?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inheritance, interface, composition

I need to implement a basic behaviour for many classes. To make an example, let's say it is a sort of drawing behaviour: there are many different type of objects that may be drawn, and they all need a few attributes and some common code to implement the drawing process. Let's say I put this common part in a class called Drawable.

The problem is that these different classes may well be extending other classes, so I can't have them inherit from Drawable. The obvious solution would be using an interface (IDrawable), but then I couldn't implement any code in it; another solution I can think of would use composition, by creating a DrawAction class that all of my classes would instantiate, but this would require me to put the same code (if just a couple of lines) in all the classes that I need to make drawable.

Can someone please give me suggestions on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a pretty good handle on it.  What is your question specifically?  Yes, base classes can be inherited, just like an interface (but you can only inherit from one base class -- there's no multiple inheritance of classes in c#).  If you need multiple inheritance, you will have to use some sort of composition to get it.

Comment: My question, specifically, is that I would like to avoid having to use composition in the many many "derived" classes that I will have :-) Please look at the comment to the answer below for a more detailed explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the Decorator pattern may be appropriate for what you are trying to achieve.

[See Decorator Pattern Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

- Instead of trying to inherit the common "Drawing" logic, place the common logic in another class ie, a "Draw**er**"
- When an object must be drawn, pass it to the appropriate Draw**er** (or make a Draw**er** for it)
- You may still find an IDrawable interface useful so that the Draw**er** code can be written against a known interface.
- You may end up with multiple Draw**er** implementations (in which case you will need to handle dynamic selection of the appropriate Drawer for each object to be drawn)

Comment: The Decorator pattern may be helpful. I would make the decorator wrap a reference to an interface, so that the common part is delegated to the decorator, and the "custom" part (the one which depends on the "derived" classes) is exposed through the interface and used by the decorator. As soon as I'm home I'll try to implement this and I'll get back to you. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 5):

You can create instance of `DrawAction` class and then just inject it into other classes using constructor dependency injection rather than explicitly instantiating it by each class, this give you less coupled design as well:

```
IDrawAction drawAction = new DrawAction();
var drawable = new Drawable(drawAction);

public class Drawable
{
    public Drawable(IDrawAction drawAction)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I would still need to write code that uses the 'IDrawAction' object, and this code could not be in an interface. 

Plus, I wouldn't really need to have different 'IDrawAction' behaviours in different "derived" classes. Theoretically, there would be no problem in having all the client classes inherit from a concrete base class, as they will all need to do the same thing (as far as the drawing is concerned); the only problem is that if they inherit from a non-interface type then they cannot inherit from any other non-interface type, a limitation I can't live with.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a situation for [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), rather than inheritance.

You could implement the drawing behavior in one class, and then have all the classes that need it maintain a reference to it.

If you need to support many different drawing algorithms, you might want to look at the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).  Here you would implement many different drawing algorithms, all implementing some sort of interface, and the object that needs to draw would have a reference to one of them.

Depending on your situation, if certain types of objects always need a certain type of drawing algorithm, the selection of which drawing class could be automated with the use of an IoC container, like [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/) or [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/).

Here's an example of the strategy pattern from [DoFactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Adam! While I already knew about Strategy Pattern, I didn't know about StructureMap, nor about Unity. From a quick glance, it looks like Unity may help me, but I want to make sure we're on the same wavelength.

Here's a more detailed example. By using composition, I would have something like
`class Foo
{
 DrawAction m_oDrawAction = new DrawAction();
 public override void Draw()
 {
  m_oDrawAction.Do();
 }
 // other stuff exclusive to Foo
}`
and I would need to copy this into every class that I need to draw. Is there a way to avoid this error-prone code duplication?

Answer (score 2):

You can create extension methods for `IDrawable`:

```
public static class DrawableExtensions
{
    public static int CalculateSize(this IDrawable drawable)
    {
         return drawable.Width * drawable.Height;
    }
}
```

This way these methoda apear to be on the `IDrawable` interface:

```
IDrawable d = new Circle();

int size = d.CalculateSize();
```

The downside is that extension methods are static and you can't override them.

Comment: Thanks Steven! I didn't know of this feature; thanks for talking about it. I'm afraid, though, that it wouldn't help me as to my problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't supports multiple inheritance. Stop. You cannot do that.
You are talking about "Mixins"... that are still not supported in C#.

However there are several alternatives you can use.

The simpler one is to use a Mixin class that you can add as a field in all your classes.
For example...

```
public class DrawerMixin
{
    public void DrawRectangle() { ... }
}

public class MyClass1 : Component
{
    public DrawerMixin Drawer { get; private set; }

    public MyClass1()
    {
        this.Drawer = new DrawerMixin(this);
    }

    public MyClass1(DrawerMixin drawer)
    {
        this.Drawer = drawer;
    }

    public void MyFunc()
    {
        ...
        this.Drawer.DrawRectangle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Salvatore, thanks for your comment! In fact this is what I was thinking of when I talked about using composition. As I described in another comment, though, I would love to get rid of the code duplication needed to instantiate the mixin in my "derived" classes. 

In C/C++, I would use a macro to instantiate the mixin. I would still need to include the macro in each "derived" class, but I would only need to edit the macro for every class to be updated. Is there at least a way to do something like this in C#?